# How to import a library GMP into Sage/Python project

Tags: python, sage

I have already installed the GMP library, Now i want to import this library to sage project
i tried to put :

```
      import libgmpxx.so.4

      libgmpxx.so.4.path.append('usr/local/lib/')
```

but it does'nt work unfortunately, how can i do that. 
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sage's Integer class uses GMP (or MPIR) automatically. If you are trying to use GMP independently of Sage, look at [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/).

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of gmpy.